# CodeIgniter image watermark returns blank image when using dynamic output

Tags: php, jquery, codeigniter, gd

I'm using jquery to post data to a controller function which watermarks an image located on the server and dynamically posts it back. The watermark function works when I'm not using dynamic output, but when I do it just returns a blank image with a 1 pixel gray border around it.

The returned image is named correctly and has the correct image type headers applied to it. This is the first line from the gobble-de-gook returned in the network inspector:

```
ÿØÿàJFIFÿþ;CREATOR: gd-jpeg v1.0 (using IJG JPEG v90), quality = 90
```

Any alternative methods of accomplishing this would be appreciated, have spent days on this now with little success. I'd prefer to leave the image on the server untouched if at all possible.

Java:

```
$('#body').on('click', '#get_file', function(ev)
{
    ev.preventDefault();

    var type = 'file';
    var uid = $('#file_select').val();

    var v1 = retD['res'][0].v1;
    var v2 = retD['res'][0].v2;
    var v3 = retD['res'][0].v3;
    var v4 = retD['res'][0].v4;

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '<?php echo site_url("Home_controller/drawInfo") ?>',
        data: {v1:v1, v2:v2, v3:v3, v4:v4},
        dataType: 'html',
        success: function(img)
        {
            $("#i").attr("src", img);
        }
    }); 
});
```

controller:

```
function drawInfo()
{
    $v1 = $_POST['v1'];
    $v2 = $_POST['v2'];
    $v3 = $_POST['v3'];
    $v4 = $_POST['v4'];

    $config['image_library'] = 'gd2';
    $config['source_image'] = './img/Test_image.jpg';
    $config['wm_text'] = 'v1: ' . $v1 . ' v2: ' . $v2 . ' v3: ' . $v3 . ' v4: ' . $v4;
    $config['wm_type'] = 'text';
    $config['dynamic_output'] = true;
    $config['wm_font_color'] = 'ff0000';
    $config['wm_font_path'] = './system/fonts/texb.ttf';
    $config['wm_vrt_alignment'] = 'bottom';
    $config['wm_hor_alignment'] = 'center';
    $config['wm_padding'] = '20';

    $this->image_lib->initialize($config); 

    if(!$this->image_lib->watermark())
    {
        echo $this->image_lib->display_errors();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the controller you return back with the image binary data, however in the Javascript you want to use it as the 'src' attribute of the img element.

In the controller you should return with the src of the newly generated image.
Please be careful when you set the paths and set the right permission to the folder where you will generate the images (it should be writable by apache).

Controller:

```
function drawInfo()
{
    $return = array(
        'src'   => '',
        'error' => '',
    );
    $v1 = $_POST['v1'];
    $v2 = $_POST['v2'];
    $v3 = $_POST['v3'];
    $v4 = $_POST['v4'];

    $config['image_library'] = 'gd2';
    // set image path
    $config['source_image'] = FCPATH . 'img/Test_image.jpg';
    // this image will be watermarked (path should be writable by apache!!!)
    $config['new_image'] = FCPATH . 'img/Test_image_new.jpg';
    $config['wm_text'] = 'v1: ' . $v1 . ' v2: ' . $v2 . ' v3: ' . $v3 . ' v4: ' . $v4;
    $config['wm_type'] = 'text';
    // to false to save image to file instead of print it (you can leave this setting because the false is the default value)
    $config['dynamic_output'] = false;
    $config['wm_font_color'] = 'ff0000';
    // set the proper path!!
    $config['wm_font_path'] = FCPATH . 'system/fonts/texb.ttf';
    $config['wm_vrt_alignment'] = 'bottom';
    $config['wm_hor_alignment'] = 'center';
    $config['wm_padding'] = '20';

    $this->image_lib->initialize($config);

    if(!$this->image_lib->watermark())
    {
        $return['error'] = $this->image_lib->display_errors();
    }
    else 
    {
        // generate the URL of the new watermarked image (modify to your needs)
        $return['src'] = base_url() .'/'. $config['new_image'];
    }
    echo json_encode($return);
}
```

JavaScript:

```
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '<?php echo site_url("Home_controller/drawInfo") ?>',
        data: {v1:v1, v2:v2, v3:v3, v4:v4},
        dataType: 'html',
        success: function(response)
        {
            if(response.error) 
            {
                alert(response.error);
            }
            else 
            {
                $("#i").attr("src", response.src);    
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: Sorry dude, doesn't work - JS ignores the response (which is still image data and not an encoded array) I think the issue is that when dynamic_output is enabled GD/CI just returns an image directly - the return array isn't even being passed. Shame, I was really hoping this was going to do the trick :(

Comment: Just drop the $config['dynamic_output'] setting or set it to false. (I modified the code).

Comment: Yup that works, it does create an image on the server which I was hoping to avoid, but deleting the image once it's been served to the browser is of no consequence. TVM mate, I wasted days trying to get that working!